# HttpResponse object becomes string when passed to assertContains

Tags: django, django-testing, django-unittest

I have a strange problem in a Django template test.  When the test executes my view, the view returns an HttpResponse object.  However, when I then pass that response object to the Django TestCase assertContains method, the response object becomes a string.  Since this string doesn't have a 'status_code' attribute like a response object does, the test fails.  Here's my code:

## template_tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import RequestFactory

class TestUploadMainPhotoTemplate(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def test_user_selects_non_jpeg_photo_file(self):
        """
        User is trying to upload a photo file via a form
        with an ImageField.  However, the file doesn't have
        a '.jpg' extension so the form's is_valid function, which
        I've overridden, flags this as an error and returns False.
        """
        with open('photo.png') as test_photo:
            request = self.factory.post(reverse('upload-photo'), 
                                        {'upload_photo': '[Upload Photo]',
                                         'photo': test_photo})
        kwargs = {'template': 'upload_photo.html'}
        response = upload_photo(request, **kwargs)
        # pdb.set_trace()
        self.assertContains(response, 'Error: photo file must be a JPEG file')
```

When I run this code in the debugger and do 'type(response)' before I call assertContains, I can see that 'response' is a HttpResponse object.  However, when assertContains is called, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

I set an additional breakpoint in the assertContains method at the location .../django/test/testcases.py:638:

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status_code...
```

At this point, when I do 'type(response)' again, I see that it has become a string object and doesn't have a status_code attribute.  Can anyone explain what's going on?  I've used this same test pattern successfully in a dozen other template tests and it worked in all of them.  Could it have something to do with the fact that this test involves uploading a file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by looking at assertContains, it doesn't really help you but who knows ?

```
void assertContains( SimpleTestCase self, WSGIRequest response, text, count = ..., int status_code = ..., string msg_prefix = ..., bool html = ... )
```

*Asserts that a response indicates that some content was retrieved
successfully, (i.e., the HTTP status code was as expected), and that
`text` occurs `count` times in the content of the response.
If `count` is None, the count doesn't matter - the assertion is true
if the text occurs at least once in the response.*

> Could it have something to do with the fact that this test involves uploading a file?

Sure, as I successfully wrote my test for a simple HttpResponse :

```
response = self.client.get('/administration/', follow=True)
self.assertContains(response, '<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">',msg_prefix="The page should use Bootstrap")
```

So I am not really helping, but maybe this could help somebody a little.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem handling Json Response .

```
self.assertEquals(json.loads(response.content),{'abc': True})
```

Following fixed the problem for me.